# Android make a case sensitive menu option

Tags: android, android-menu

I want is a go from a menu that has a list of objects, if you select an option menu another list should appear.

The examples I found seemed to be for listview or webview.

There another way to make a selection from menu options?

Comment: Could you please make the question a little clearer? Do you want the person to be able to click on an item in a menu and when doing so launch a context menu?

Comment: @KurtisNusbaum Yea sorry, for not being more clear

Comment: that's cool just go back and edit your question so it's more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I'm understanding your right, you want to launch a [Context Menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu) from an [Options Menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu). You should not do this. From the android documentation:

> A context menu is conceptually similar to the menu displayed when the user performs a "right-click" on a PC. You should use a context menu to provide the user access to actions that pertain to a specific item in the user interface. On Android, a context menu is displayed when the user performs a "long press" (press and hold) on an item.

You'd never do a "long press" on an Options Menu item. People just aren't used to doing that.

Try launching another activity instead or using a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed list of options in mind you might be looking for submenus, which are explained here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

If you are looking to dynamically build a list of options with an adapter you might find [AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html) useful along with its `setAdapter` method.